# How to prevent ruby on rails from creating html code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I prevent ruby on rails from create html code. How do I let it only read code in the .html.erb file.
When I put code in the .html.erb file the code places itself in the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Overcasty</title>
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="6TmCd0ZIQF0IP/iNnieQZ8IIPDQyZUe6jSBthuGfZDg=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller turn off the layout during rendering:

```
render layout: false
```

Or turn it off for the controller for particular actions, e.g.,

```
layout "product", :except => [:index]
```

Or turn it off completely:

```
layout false
```

The behavior you see is standard, default behavior. I'd recommend reading over the [Layouts and Rendering docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) since all this is covered very well there, and in essentially any Rails tutorial.

I'd recommend examining the framework a bit more to see if this is really the appropriate solution.